# Problems with SystemParametersInfo function

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp

Please help.
I want to change system-wide parameters with SystemParametersInfo function. I use Visual Studio 2008 in Windows XP.
Here is my code

```
NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
memset(&ncm,0,sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS));
ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
#if (WINVER >= 0x0600)
    ncm.cbSize -= 4;
#endif

if(SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS,sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0)!=0)
{
    wcscpy_s(ncm.lfCaptionFont.lfFaceName,L"Sylfaen");
    wcscpy_s(ncm.lfMenuFont.lfFaceName,L"Sylfaen");
    wcscpy_s(ncm.lfMessageFont.lfFaceName,L"Sylfaen");
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS,sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0);
}
```

The code works fluently, but the icons of the systray are become big